# What's wrong with this Fortran 90-95 code for simulating water flow through non-saturated soil?

Tags: fortran

I've been working for many days trying to find out what's wrong with this code. It's used for modelling water flow through non saturated soil. The equations system is in the form of a tridiagonal matrix, which is solved with the Thomas Algorithm. I have the solution, and the code is not representing it. For example, node A should be a curve that goes from the initial condition of aprox -100 cm to aprox -20 cm. It's a long code, but I'd be tremendously thankful if someone helped me in this one.

```
program EcuacionRichards

implicit none

!Declaring variables

integer, parameter :: nodos = 100
integer :: i, it, max_it, nodo_a, nodo_b, nodo_c, nodo_d, it_bajo, it_alto
double precision, dimension(1:nodos) :: H, H_ant, C, K, theta, theta_ant, aa, bb, cc, dd, rr, th_ant
double precision :: dz, zbot, tfin, dt, rz, Ksup, Kinf, t, th_lisimetro, h_lisimetro  
double precision :: q_ent, tol_h, tol_th, cambio_h, cambio_th
double precision :: mult_alto, mult_bajo, maxdt, mindt, qlibre
logical lisimetro

!Hydraulic Parameters
double precision :: theta_sat=0.43      !cm/cm 
double precision :: theta_res=0.078     !cm/cm
double precision :: alpha=0.0325        !1/cm
double precision :: n=1.346
double precision :: m
double precision :: K_sat=86.4          !cm/d

!Grid and iteration parameters
lisimetro=.true.
dt=0.01             !days
zbot=160            !depth of the column in cm
dz=zbot/nodos       !cm
tfin=30             !days
max_it=500          !max number of Picard iterations
tol_h=0.1           !tolerance for H iteration, cm
tol_th=0.001        !tolerance for theta iteration, 1/1
it_bajo=3           !minimum recommended number of iterations
it_alto=7           !maximum recommended number of iterations
mult_bajo=1.3       !time multiplicator for low iterations
mult_alto=0.7       !time multiplicator for low iterations
maxdt=0.5           !max value for dt 
mindt=0.001         !min value for dt 
m=1-1/n

!Initializing other variables
th_lisimetro=0.32
h_lisimetro=HfTH(th_lisimetro)

nodo_a=nodos
nodo_b=2*nodos/3
nodo_c=nodos/3
nodo_d=1

!*********Initial Conditions************************************************************

call theta_ini(theta,nodos) !Fill array with initial moisture values
do i=1,nodos
    H(i)=HfTH(theta(i))
    call actualiza(H(i), theta(i), C(i), K(i))
end do

!************* OPEN WRITING FILES ************************************************
open(unit=1,file='succion2.txt')
open(unit=2,file='humedad2.txt')
open(unit=3,file='conducti2.txt')
open(unit=4,file='parametr2.txt')
write(4,'("dt(días) =",f7.4)') dt 
write(4,'("dz(cm) =",f7.4)') dz
write(4,'("nodos =",i5)') nodos
write(4,'("altura(cm) =",f8.3)') zbot
write(4,'("tfin(días) =",f7.2)') tfin
write(4,'("theta_sat =",f7.4)') theta_sat
write(4,'("theta_res =",f7.4)') theta_res
write(4,'("K_saturada =",g11.3)') K_sat
write(4,'("n =",f7.4)') n
write(4,'("m =",f7.5)') m
write(4,'("alpha =",f7.5)') alpha
write(4,'("max_it =",i4)') max_it
close(4)
write(1,*) "T(días) H_a(cm) H_b(cm) H_c(cm) H_d(cm)"
write(2,*) "T(días) th_a(cm) th_b(cm) th_c(cm) th_d(cm)"
write(3,*) "T(días) K_a(cm/d) K_b(cm/d) K_c(cm/d) K_d(cm/d)" 


!*************TIME LOOP**********************************************************************************************
t=0.d0
do while ((t.le.tfin).and.(dt.gt.0))
    rz=dz/dt
    t=t+dt
    theta_ant=theta !Previous time
    !Water flow that enters at the top (constant)
    q_ent=0.1       !cm/dia
!*************     PICARD LOOP              ******************************************
Picard:do it=1,max_it

            if(it.eq.max_it) pause "MAXIMUM ITERATIONS REACHED"

            !Interior Nodes
            do i=2, nodos-1
                 Ksup=2*(K(i+1)*K(i))/(K(i+1)+K(i))
                 Kinf=2*(K(i-1)*K(i))/(K(i-1)+K(i))
                 aa(i)=-Kinf/dz !K(i-1/2)
                 cc(i)=-Ksup/dz !K(i+1/2)
                 bb(i)=rz*C(i)-aa(i)-cc(i)
                 rr(i)=rz*C(i)*h(i)-rz*(theta(i)-theta_ant(i))+Ksup-Kinf
            end do

            !Inferior Node
            if (lisimetro) then
              !Changing inferior node
              if (theta(1).lt.th_lisimetro) then
                    !Water flow 0, Neumann
                    Ksup=2*(K(1)*K(2))/(K(1)+K(2))
                    aa(1)=0
                    cc(1)=-Ksup/dz
                    bb(1)=-cc(1)
                    rr(1)=Ksup
              else
                    !H(1)=0 condition, Dirichlet
                    Ksup=2*(K(1)*K(2))/(K(1)+K(2))
                    aa(1)=0
                    bb(1)=1
                    cc(1)=0
                    rr(1)=h_lisimetro
                    aa(2)=0
                    rr(2)=rr(2)+Ksup/dz*(h_lisimetro)
              end if
            else
              !Inferior node, free drainage, Neumann
              Ksup=2*(K(1)*K(2))/(K(1)+K(2))
              qlibre=-K(1)
              aa(1)=0
              cc(1)=-Ksup/dz
              bb(1)=-cc(1)
              rr(1)=Ksup+qlibre
            end if

            !Superior node, known water flow
            Kinf=2*(K(nodos)*K(nodos-1))/(K(nodos)+K(nodos-1))
            aa(nodos)=-Kinf/dz
            cc(nodos)=0
            bb(nodos)=0.5*rz*C(nodos)-aa(nodos)
            rr(nodos)=0.5*rz*C(nodos)*h(nodos)-0.5*rz*(theta(nodos)-theta_ant(nodos))-Kinf-q_ent

            call tridiag(aa,bb,cc,rr,dd,nodos)

            !Suction modification and H functions actualization
            h_ant=h
            th_ant=theta !Save iteration
            h=dd         !Advance to next iteration 
            do i=1,nodos
                call actualiza(H(i),theta(i), C(i), K(i))
            end do

            !End of iterations condition
            cambio_h=maxval(dabs(h-h_ant))
            cambio_th=maxval(dabs(theta-th_ant))

            if((cambio_h.lt.tol_h).and.(cambio_th.lt.tol_th)) then

                if(.true.) then !(t.eq.tprint)
                write (1,'(f8.3,f9.3,f9.3,f9.3,f9.3)') t,H(nodo_a),H(nodo_b),H(nodo_c),H(nodo_d)
                write (2,'(f8.3,f7.4,f7.4,f7.4,f7.4)') t,theta(nodo_a),theta(nodo_b),theta(nodo_c),theta(nodo_d)
                write (3,'(f8.3,g11.4,g11.4,g11.4,g11.4)') t,k(nodo_a),k(nodo_b),k(nodo_c),k(nodo_d)
                end if

                if (it.lt.it_bajo) dt=min(dt*mult_bajo,maxdt)
                if (it.gt.it_alto) dt=max(dt*mult_alto,mindt)

                exit Picard

            else
                cycle Picard
            end if
       end do Picard !Picard loop end
       if ((tfin-t).le.1E-4) t=huge(1.d0)
end do
!Time Loop End***************************************************************
!******** Close files
close(1)
close(2)
close(3)

!********END OF PROGRAM**********************************************************
!******************************************************************************
!Subroutines and functions
contains

!Initial moistures assignment
subroutine theta_ini(theta,nodos)
integer :: nodos
double precision, dimension(1:nodos) :: theta
integer i
do i=1, nodos
    theta(i)=0.30
end do
end subroutine theta_ini

!Subroutine that actualizes salues according to pressure
subroutine actualiza(p,theta,c,k)
    double precision p, theta, c, k
    double precision se, te
    if(p.lt.0) then           
                  te=1+(-alpha*p)**n
                  se=te**(-m)
                  theta=theta_res+(theta_sat-theta_res)*se
                  K=K_sat*se**(0.5)*(1-(1-se**(1/m))**m)**2
                  c=((alpha**n)*(theta_sat-theta_res)*n*m*(-p)**(n-1))/(te**(m+1)) !d(theta)/dh
    else 
                  theta=theta_sat
                  K=K_sat
                  c=0
    end if
    return
end subroutine actualiza

!Tridiag(alpha,beta, gamma, Resto, delta, nodos)
      subroutine tridiag(a,b,c,d,x,n)
      implicit none
!        a - sub-diagonal (means it is the diagonal below the main diagonal)
!        b - the main diagonal
!        c - sup-diagonal (means it is the diagonal above the main diagonal)
!        d - right part
!        x - the answer
!        n - number of equations

        integer,intent(in) :: n
        double precision,dimension(n),intent(in) :: a,b,c,d
        double precision,dimension(n),intent(out) :: x
        double precision,dimension(n) :: cp,dp
        double precision :: m
        integer i

! initialize c-prime and d-prime
        cp(1) = c(1)/b(1)
        dp(1) = d(1)/b(1)
! solve for vectors c-prime and d-prime
         do i = 2,n
           m = b(i)-cp(i-1)*a(i)
           cp(i) = c(i)/m
           dp(i) = (d(i)-dp(i-1)*a(i))/m
         enddo
! initialize x
         x(n) = dp(n)
! solve for x from the vectors c-prime and d-prime
        do i = n-1, 1, -1
          x(i) = dp(i)-cp(i)*x(i+1)
        end do

    end subroutine tridiag

!Head in terms of moisture
Function HfTH(humedad)
    double precision HfTH
    double precision humedad
    if (humedad.lt.theta_sat) then
              HfTH=-1/alpha*(((humedad-theta_res)/(theta_sat-theta_res))**(-1/m)-1)**(1/n) !cm
    else
              HfTH=0
    end if
    Return
end function HfTH

end program EcuacionRichards
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not representing it"? You should make an attempt at debugging before you ask SO to do it.

Comment: I suggest breaking it up into pieces (subroutines and functions) and, as much as possible, testing the pieces.  Maybe split off further subroutines from your main program.  I don't like subroutines as "contains" off the main program ... better to put into a module and use that module.  The current way they inherit variables ... that can be very confusing.

Comment: Looks like someone copied my tridiagonal solver from Wikipedia (not that I made the algorithm, just the previous version posted was not correct so I corrected it).

Comment: I already debugged it, if I had found the mistake, I wouldn't have asked anything here ;)
I was using another tridiagonal solver, so to test if that was the mistake, I copied the one in Wikipedia in the code. That wasn't the mistake, but I just didn't change it back.

Answer (score 2):

I can see any number of problems with your code but my attention span is limited so here is just the most egregious

You declare a bunch of variables to be `double precision`, for example, `theta_sat`, yet you initialise them with literals of default kind.  The statement

```
double precision :: theta_sat=0.43      !cm/cm
```

does not make `0.43` a `double precision` real.  Well, to be accurate, it might but on most compilers, and whenever the compilation does not set default real variables to kind `double precision`, it doesn't.  It is almost certain that `0.43` is a 4-byte real while `theta_sat` is an 8-byte real and you cannot rely on the compiler to set `theta_sat` to be the 8-byte value closest to `0.43`.

In modern Fortran `double precision` is still available for backward compatibility, but deprecated in favour of specifying the kind of a variable with a kind type.  SO is replete with suggestions of how to do this.  My favourite is to use the constants defined in the intrinsic module `iso_fortran_env`, like this:

```
use, intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env
```

then declare variables like this:

```
real(real64) :: theta_sat=0.43_real64      !cm/cm
```

note the appending of the kind specification `_real64` to the value.

Whether your algorithm is sensitive enough that this mistake on your part materially affects the results I don't know.

Finally, you tell us that the program is not correct but you are silent on the way(s) in which it is not correct.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll try fixing that.
The program is not correct because I know what the correct results are (generated by HYDRUS) and I'm trying to validate the program with them.
For example, for node A the program, for H, obtains a result that goes from the initial condition (-100 cm aprox) down to less than -9000 cm, when in fact it goes up from -100 to -20 cm.
Another thing, depending on dz, the program crashes into a error of arithmetic overflow. For example, it works for dz = 1 cm, but collapses for dz = 1,6 cm. Could it be related to what you answered me before?

Comment: You certainly need to understand whether or not your implementation is *stable*.  If you are not completely familiar with this concept start your reading at the Wikipedia article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_stability  What you tell us about the impact of changing `dz` makes me suspect that your implementation is unstable.  You have to develop an acute understanding of how the output of your program changes wrt small changes to inputs and parameters and of whether those changes are valid for the mathematical model you are implementing, or not.

Comment: The "use, intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env" command is available in Fortran 90-95?

Comment: No, that module was introduced in Fortran 2003, but the recent editions of most of the common Fortran compilers provide it.

Comment: I'm using a compiler named Plato, which doesn't support that command. Which Fortran compiler would you recommend using? (this is the first program in Fortran I've written, that's why I don't have much experience).

Comment: Plato isn't a Fortran compiler, it's an IDE which is an optional add-on for the SilverFrost compiler.  I don't make recommendations (not without a lot more information about your requirements and not without payment) but this site - http://www.polyhedron.com/compare0html - might be of assistance.  But changing your compiler is an unnecessary distraction, Fortran 95 provides the means to specify the kind of real literals, investigate `selected_real_kind` and its use.